# Perform task after firebase value changes

Tags: angular, firebase-realtime-database, angularfire2

In Angular 7 I'm trying to perform a task such as play an audio when the data changes in my firebase realtime data. When I implement the code nothing shows up on the screen and sound doesn't play.

```
constructor(db: AngularFireDatabase){   
    this.values = db.list('values/').valueChanges().subscribe((data)=>
      this.playAudio
    );
}
playAudio(){
    let audio = new Audio();
    audio.src = ".././assets/audio/notsoconfident.mp3"; 
    audio.load();
    audio.play();
}
```

I've checked the audio resource and it is correct. The information updates with the value changes but when I try to //do something// when the value changes it becomes useless. What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: You're missing `()` after `this.playAudio`, which means the function is not invoked. So use `this.playAudio()` instead.

Comment: Thanks. I did forget the (). I added it but then it gave me an error for `this.values` saying "Type 'Subscription' is missing the following properties from type 'Observable<any[]>". As a result, I decided to add this line to subscribe:
`this.values.subscribe(values => {
      this.playAudio();
    })`